# How to connect MySQL client with server running in Docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I am using Docker first time. I am trying  to connect docker based MySQL with my Navicat client. How do I get docker IP and then use it for connection? Here are a few details:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
b984b6659d20        mysql:5.7                "docker-entrypoint.sh"   8 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        3306/tcp                                   myre_mysql_run_1
d34d8974912c        myre_php-apache-engine   "/usr/local/bin/entry"   20 hours ago        Up 7 minutes        80/tcp                                     myre_php_apache_engine_dev
981c2a7fa83b        mysql:5.7                "docker-entrypoint.sh"   20 hours ago        Up 47 seconds       3306/tcp                                   myre_mysql_dev
472531e09d08        jwilder/nginx-proxy      "/app/docker-entrypoi"   20 hours ago        Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   nginx_proxy
```

Answer (score 8):

If you need to access the mysql container from the outside. Than you need to map the container port on the port of your server (using `-p`).

```
docker run --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw  -e MYSQL_USER=test -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=test -d mysql:latest
```

Now you can connect to your container using the IP of your server + the port. In my case I'm in a VLAN. The IP of my server is 192.168.140.30. So e.g. when I ssh to my server I use that IP. Now I've mapped the port of my container on the port of my server (with `-p 3306:3306` which means: map the port 3306 of my container to port 3306 of my server. (so I can use the server IP to connect).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Will this commend restart already running MySQL? Yes My Navicat client is on my laptop where Docker is installed

Comment: The first command will start a new mysql-container. You need to expose and map the port when the container starts. So if you did not do this you'll need to delete your old mysql and restart it with the command above. (Don't know if you use `-v` to reuse your volume)

Comment: You'll need to map `-p 3306:3306` and you can use localhost:3306 in your Navicat.

Comment: In which file should I mention it so that it always run? in `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: Are you starting your containers with docker-compose? Then you should do something like here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/version-2 (check the port in the config). But if it's your first experience with docker I would recommended to perform the docker run commands manually in your bash like explained in the answers.

Comment: I am using my team's code.. I already tried adding `ports` section but on running commands it is removing the section from the `.yml` file

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have enough information to solve your problem. Maybe contact your team.

Answer (score 0):

If you need use client to connect to MySQL in Docker container you need do port mapping with the host machine.

I see you MySQL container not use mapping the container port to host port so you can not use MySQL client to connect the MySQL server.

You can use -p parameter specify the port mapping. for example if you need use port 3306 to connect to MySQL server, use following command to create the MySQL container. PS: you need change some setting for following command.

```
docker run --name container-name -d -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=database-name -e MYSQL_USER=user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password  mysql:5.7
```